# VCard reader not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, vcf-vcard

I am new to objective C and I am in a position where I need create an App urgently . I am using XCode 4.2

in a part of the App I will be detecting a QR code and getting a VCard in NSString format :
I did the function using the following code :
-I imported the following to frameworks :

```
AddressBookUI.framework
AddressBook.framework
```

in the .h file I wrote :

```
#import <addressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

@interface HellowWorld : UIViewController<ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>{

}

-(IBAction)saveContacts;
@end
```

in the .m file I wrote :

```
-(IBAction)saveContacts{
    NSString *vCardString = test //where the data will be comming from
    CFDataRef vCardData = (CFDataRef)[vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreate(); 
    ABRecordRef defaultSource = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(book); 
    CFArrayRef vCardPeople = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource, vCardData); 
    for (CFIndex index = 0; index < CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople); index++) {     
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(vCardPeople, index);     
        ABAddressBookAddRecord(book, person, NULL);     
        CFRelease(person); 
    }  
    CFRelease(vCardPeople); 
    CFRelease(defaultSource); 
    ABAddressBookSave(book, NULL); 
    CFRelease(book); 
}
```

I used this code but it is not working.

First it did not compile this line :

```
CFDataRef vCardData = (CFDataRef)[vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I had to change it to this :

```
CFDataRef vCardData = (__bridge CFDataRef)[vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and after compiling it crashes at this line :

```
 for (CFIndex index = 0; index < CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople); index++) {
```

It gives the following green error : `Thread1: Program Received Signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"`.
Any reasons?

also is this the only way to save a VCard (in NSString format) in the address book ? any other suggestions ?

Comment: "I am `new to objective C` and I am in a position where I need `create an App urgently`" : Ohhhh, my god.... Ohhh, my god....

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have ARC enabled.

Does `CFRetain`ing the `vCardData` object while you use it stop the crash? The data object probably only survives until the end of the scope.

Or possibly better, use `__bridge_retained`

See the [release notes on ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-DontLinkElementID_5)

Comment: I tried __bridge_retained and it is still not working

I am not sure that I understand your question , it crashes at the for loop

Comment: @user1044771: Have you checked that `vCardPeople` is non null and is an array?

Comment: I checked to make sure (basically i inialized a text)
and now it doesn t crash but it doesn t save in the address book , any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Import Vcard data to Iphone Contact List do following.

Add `AddressbookUi.framework`

Add `Addressbook.framework`

Include this headers:

```
#include AddressBook/ABAddressBook.h>
#include AddressBook/ABRecord.h>
#include AddressBook/ABSource.h>
```

And call this function:

```
-(void)importVcard {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *startPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *filename  = @"contacts.vcf";
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",startPath,filename];
    NSLog(@"File Path is %@",startPath);

    NSString *vCardString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil ];

    CFDataRef vCardData = (CFDataRef)[vCardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreate(); 
    ABRecordRef defaultSource = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(book); 

    CFArrayRef vCardPeople = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource, vCardData); 

    for (CFIndex index = 0; index < CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople); index++) {     
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(vCardPeople, index);     
        ABAddressBookAddRecord(book, person, NULL);     
        CFRelease(person); 
    }  

    CFRelease(vCardPeople); 
    CFRelease(defaultSource); 
    ABAddressBookSave(book, NULL); 
    CFRelease(book); 
}
```

Comment: did you got swift version?